# Composer generates incorrect composer.lock after composer update

Tags: composer-php

My `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "5.6.*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^5.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "~1.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "reliese/laravel": "^0.0.13",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Output of `composer diagnose`:

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: FAIL
Missing pubkey for tags verification
Missing pubkey for dev verification
Run composer self-update --update-keys to set them up
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 1.6.3
PHP version: 7.2.2-3+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php7.2
```

When I run this command:

```
composer update
```

I get the following output:

```
ATTENTION! Big file ~5k lines, the composer.lock
https://pastebin.com/1Jc1HqRj
```

And I expected this to happen:
The predis/predis package should be at the "require" section of the composer.lock, not in "require-dev".
So, how to move it from the composer .lock's require-dev section to the simple require? I use Heroku and need it in to the simple "require" section in the composer.lock.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your composer.lock is correct.
You have to look for "packages" resp. "packages-dev".

predis/predis is listed under "packages", so its listed for production.

So what you list in composer.json require section should eventually go to packages in composer.lock and require-dev should go to packages-dev.

I think you were lookig at the predis/predis entry in require-dev section of laravel/framework.
This is only valid for laravel/framework but not for your project.